# Real-world, enterprise developer best practices for Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to create a simple pipeline with a few activities. The solution to start off won't be very complex - we'll pull in a spreadsheet from Sharepoint, parse it, transform it and stage it a SQL Azure database. Over time, the solution will have many other similar pipelines of varying complexity.

How should I structure the solution? Should I build everything directly in the Azure Portal? - there is a nice GUI after all.

Or should I follow my instinct and build out the solution in Visual Studio? If so, are there any extensions out there for VS 2022 that replicate the WYSIWYG experience of the portal? Any documentation/links around best practices for enterprise grade solutions win extra points!

Comment: I'm a long time C# developer, but I do everything in the portal.

Comment: how do multiple developers collaborate with that approach?

Comment: I didn’t think the VS ADF experience was still supported?  Recommendations are: use a naming convention, parametrise datasets and pipelines as much as possible, aim to have fewer dynamic pipelines rather than many static ones, aim for reuse of datasets and pipelines; this is achieved by up-front design.

Comment: We use Git integration and branches.